# How to display progress bar while the service is still fetching response

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a modal and I want a progress bar to be shown while the data for modal display is being fetched by the service call. But in this case, progress bar is being fetched first and then the modal which makes the progress bar to be displayed under the modal. How to fix this ?

```
 this.service.searchMembers(memSearchJson).subscribe((response: any) => {
// some function
}
```

```
<modal id="custom-modal-2">
      <div class="modal">

          </div>
          <div id="memberSearchBar" class="class-hide">
              <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
              Finding Member IDs..
        </div>
  </modal>
```

If  **document.getElementById("memberSearchBar").className = 'loading-div';** is called before the service call, it throws error as className null. Where should I call this to display progress bar on modal?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `document.getElementById("memberSearchBar").className = 'loading-div'` you can take advantage of Angular's `*ngIf` and `[class.class-name]="expression"`

Try something like this instead

```
displayModalAndSearchMembers(){
 // using only isLoading should be sufficient, but I wanted to show how you could use [class.classname]="expression" in the html template as well.
 this.isLoading = true; 
 this.showSpinner = true;
 this.displayModal = true;

 this.service.searchMembers(memSearchJson).subscribe((response: any) => {
  // some function
  this.isLoading = false;
  this.showSpinner = false;
 }
}
```

```
<modal id="custom-modal-2">
      <div *ngIf="displayModal" class="modal"> <!-- added *ngIf -->

          </div>
          <div id="memberSearchBar" *ngIf="showSpinner" [class.loading-div]="isLoading">
              <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
              Finding Member IDs..
        </div>
  </modal>
```

**EDIT**

You could also use `*ngIf="displayModal"` on the modal as well, in case you have some `display: none` on that one as well.

I added some ts code as well. I am not 100% sure what the desired behaviour OP wants, but I am assuming that she wants to show/hide the spinner, and set a class name on it.

This can be simplified by using only `*ngIf="isLoading"`:

`<div id="memberSearchBar" class="loading-div" *ngIf="showSpinner">`

Comment: Okay, and in that case I have  to showSpinner as true / false  in TS file to control the display right ?   this.tdmService.searchMembers(memSearchJson).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.showSpinner = true;}

Comment: not 100% sure what your code should do, but when the subscription triggers, you should HIDE the spinner (this.showSpinner = false). Set showSpinner to true in e.g. ngOnInit, reset it to false when you got data

Comment: @RK1605 almost correct. You show the spinner before you do the searchMethod, and then you hide it after the search method is complete.

Comment: Spinner is not seen yet :/

Comment: Then I am not sure why it is not working. If you are able to put the example in a Stackblitz, it is easier to help out :) Does you `modal` class have any `display:none` maybe? You could use `*ngIf="displayModal"` on the modal instead of using display:none in css.

Comment: @John Will try to figure out the issue. *ngIf is better option that what I tried . Thanks :)

Comment: I hope you figure it out. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using *ngIf, as mentioned above. For a better understanding, I add a link to the perfect tutorial.

[Loading spinner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qR-Cj1dGgkM&list=PLQ0E4sdohxl5DFrnXJkiEJbdtORQpMjnd&index=4&t=0s)

For example: in ts:

```
   showSpinner: boolean = true;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.spinnerShow();
}
```

if you need show spinner before you get data like from service.

```
 spinnerShow(){
    this.workflowService.getData().subscribe(()=> 
   this.showSpinner = false);
  }
```

And in HTML

```
<div *ngIf="showSpinner"></div>
```

Sorry for my terrible english, but i hope this will help you. :)